# How to trace circular import error Django never solved

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-3.6, django-urls

I am working Django rest framework api project, where I had multiple apps in the project. I got a circular import error when I am adding the app URLs to the main URLs. I Tried everything checked spellings, checked app structure but no use. Its been really frustrating with issue..please help to solve the problem. The app is working fine when I take off newly added line `path("covid/", include("Covid.urls")),`

I am using python3.6, django 3.0.4 and django-rest-framework 3.11.0

Here is project
**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='TmmrwInc API Documentation')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # path('rest_auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api/password_reset/',
        include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
    # url(r'^invitations/', include('invitations.urls', namespace='invitations')),
    path('', include('rest_invitations.urls')),
    path("", include("UserAuth.urls")),
    path("doctors/", include("Administration.urls")),
    path("appointments/", include("Appointments.urls")),
    path("messaging/", include("messaging.urls")),
    path("meet/", include("meet.urls")),
    path("api_documentation/", schema_view),
    path("covid/", include("Covid.urls")),
]
```

This is app **urls.py** file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'Covid'

urlpatterns = [
    path('event/', views.EventBookingView.as_view()),
]
```

**settings.py** installed apps

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "UserAuth",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'Appointments',
    'messaging',
    'Administration',
    'channels',
    'invitations',
    'rest_invitations',
    'django_rest_passwordreset',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'meet',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
     'Covid',

]
```

here is my app **views.py** file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView, ListAPIView, UpdateAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets

from .serializers import OfficeSearchSerializer, EventSerializer, SymptomSerializer, PatientSymptomSerializer

# Create your views here

class OfficeSearchView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = OfficeSearchSerializer
    permission_class = (AllowAny,)
    lookup_field = 'pk'



class EventBookingView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    permission_class = (AllowAny, )
```

This is a project structure

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8qro.jpg)

Comment: Please share your views file screenshot in which `EventBookingView` is there.

Comment: Updated @kaushal Thanks. now please take a look where I am going wrong

Comment: Okay, so I don't see anything wrong here. The way you can debug this is by commenting out all the class except `EventBookingView`. Comment out all the code inside `EventBookingView` and remove all the imports. When all the imports are removed keep adding one import at a time and see if it breaks. One or more than one import is causing error. My guess is `.serializers` is causing error but you can debug this way.

Comment: Or you can start debugging by removing import of `.serializers`

Comment: I did tried that now, removed all unused imports and commented out other view except EventBookingView still no progress  @kaushal